# How can I check if a domain uses DNSSEC?

Tags: security, dns, certificate, domain-name

DNSSEC has been deployed on some topdomains now. But how could I see if a site/domain is using DNSSEC? Is it shown in the browser? or is there any windows or linux command to see it? or a tool for it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`dig [zone] dnskey`

That will show you if there is the required DNSKEY RRset in the zone that will be used to validate the RRsets in the zone.

If you want to see if your recursive server is validating the zone,

`dig +dnssec [zone] dnskey`

This will set the DO (dnssec OK) bit on the outbound query and cause the upstream resolver to set the AD (authenticated data) bit on the return packet if the data is validated and also provide you with the related RRSIGs (if the zone in question is signed) even if it is not able to validate the response.

You might want to take a look at the last group of slides in my ["DNSSEC in 6 Minutes" presentation](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00820) (lots about debugging DNSSEC).  That presentation is a bit long in the tooth about deploying DNSSEC (you should really look at BIND 9.7 for the good stuff), but debugging has changed little.

There is also a presentation I gave at NANOG 50 about [BIND 9.7 DNSSEC deployment](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/pubs/pres/NANOG/50/DNSSEC-NANOG50.pdf).

Comment: I've been asked over on serverfault to admit that I actually work for ISC, the maintainers of BIND and ISC DHCP.  I'm more than happy to help anyone that has issues with either one (time allowing).

Comment: Your slides for "DNSSEC in 6 minutes" give a 404 now.  Is there a new URL?

Comment: The new URL appears to be: https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00820/0/DNSSEC-in-6-minutes.html

Comment: No mention of `dig` giving a response flag of `AD`?

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe it is currently shown in the browser.

There is an extension to firefox which might do what you want:

- http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/drill/drill_extension.html

alternatively, maybe one of these tools?

- http://www.dnssec.net/software

Answer (score 0):

On Terminal:
dig tunnelix.com +dnssec

You need to find the RRSIG (RRset Signature) that points to a DNSSEC signature.

Answer from Example1:
tunnelix.com.       300 IN  RRSIG   A 13 2 300 20190515200903 20190513180903 34505 tunnelix.com. Bqc6weQYQyCi8rB3wmYxMxDqlkpOzt2wWTMC58QGy6BbX8y+jWxDIFwH DUCJ2Gy0dLFLPDNfVdZ9RmPRlbNvQw==

Otherwise, validate your DNSSEC through online free DNSSEC checker.
https://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com

For more information refer to these links which might be useful:

https://tunnelix.com/counter-dns-attack-enabling-dnssec/

https://tunnelix.com/anatomy-of-a-simple-dig-result/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I updated the answer as requested. Thanks