# How can I check if a name server supports DNSSEC?

Tags: networking, router, security, dns, nameserver

My Advanced Tomato Router uses the local ISP DNS servers. How can I see if those name servers support DNSSEC?

Similar to [How can I check if a domain uses DNSSEC?](https://superuser.com/questions/207026/how-can-i-check-if-a-domain-uses-dnssec) but not domain.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On BSD/Linux, use `dig` to send a DNS query with the `do` (request DNSSEC) flag set. (This needs a domain that's DNSSEC-signed.) For example:

```
dig +dnssec isc.org @8.8.8.8
```

If the nameserver supports DNSSEC, it'll automatically include "RRSIG" records in the reply:

```
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;isc.org.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
isc.org.        29  IN  A       149.20.64.69
isc.org.        29  IN  RRSIG   A 5 2 60 20161207234041 20161107234041 13953 isc.org. [omitted]
```

If the server doesn't understand `do`, the "Answer" section will only include what was requested:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;isc.org.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
isc.org.        60  IN  A   149.20.64.69
```